# TestCafe 'dynamic' tests cases

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I created a few e2e sanity tests for my current project using TestCafe. These tests are standard TestCafe tests:

```
fixture(`Basic checkout flow`)

test('Main Flow', async (t) => {

});
```

I would like to execute this test for multiple site locales and for multiple channels. i.e. I need this test to run for nl_nl, nl_be, en_gb, .. and also for channels like b2c, b2b, ...

The easiest way is to create a loop in the test itself to loop over the locales and channels, but I want to run these test concurrently.

I tried to create a function to dynamically generate these tests, but TestCafe can't seem to detect the tests then.

```
dynamicTest('Main Flow', async (t) => {

});

function dynamicTest(testName, testFn) => {
  const channels = ['b2c']

  channels.forEach((channel) => {
    test(`[Channel] ${channel}] ${testName}`, testFn);
  });
};
```

Is there a better way of doing this? The only solution I see is running the test script multiple times from Jenkins to have concurrency.

more detailed code:

```
import HomePage from '../../page/HomePage/HomePage';
import EnvUtil from '../../util/EnvUtil';

const wrapper = (config, testFn) => {
  config.locales.forEach(async locale =>
    config.channels.forEach(async channel => {
      const tstConfig = {
        locale,
        channel
      };

      tstConfig.env = EnvUtil.parse(tstConfig, config.args.env);
      testConfig.foo = await EnvUtil.get() // If I remove this line it works!

      testFn(config, locale, channel)
    })
  );
};

fixture(`[Feature] Feature 1`)
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    t.ctx.pages = {
      home: new HomePage(),
      ... more pages here
    };
  });

wrapper(global.config, (testConfig, locale, channel) => {
  test
    .before(async (t) => {
      t.ctx.config = testConfig;
    })
    .page(`foo.bar.com`)
    (`[Feature] [Locale: ${locale.key}] [Channel: ${channel.key}] Feature 1`, async (t) => {
      await t.ctx.pages.home.header.search(t, '3301');

      .. more test code here
    });
});
```

If I run it like this I get a "test is undefined" error. Is there something wrong in the way I'm wrapping "test"?

Comment: Would you please let me know the TestCafe version you are using?

Comment: I'm running the latest version (0.22.0)

Comment: This example works properly for me with TetstCafe v0.22: https://github.com/MarinaRukavitsyna/TestCafe_Dynamic_Test. Would you please check it?

Comment: I will check it, thanks!

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get a "test is undefined" error while running. I added my code sample in the post. Am I wrapping it wrong?

Comment: I figured out that the cause is a "await fn()" in  the wrapper file. I added it to the example. Not sure why though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TestCafe of [version 0.23.1](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v0-23-1-released.html), you can run tests imported from external libraries or generated dynamically even if the test file you provide does not contain any tests.

You can learn more here: [Run Dynamically Loaded Tests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v0-23-1-released.html#run-dynamically-loaded-tests-2074)